# Protractor: Get the text of an anchor which contains several I tags

Tags: angularjs, text, anchor, protractor

In a test case I would like to compare the text of an anchor with an expected one, but the anchor also contains i tags. Does anybody have a hint on how to do it?

E.g. (how to get the name of the selected language):

```
<a class="dropdown-button btn" href="#" data-activates="languageDropdown">
    <i class="material-icons">language</i>
    {{selectedLanguage.name}}
    <i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, select it [by Angular binding](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.binding), and then you can forget about the DOM entirely:

```
expect(element(by.binding('selectedLanguage.name')).getText()).toBe('Expected Language');
```

Comment: Thx. That works fine. I only have to call "toContain" instead of "toBe", because the texts of the I tags are also part of the text.

Comment: well, I tried it and it works. when I tried it with "toContain" I got something like this: languageENGLISHarrow_drop_down

Answer (score 0):

I really like the `by.binding()` approach presented by @SkinnyJ. Alternatively options:

```
element(by.css('a.dropdown-button'))
element(by.css('a[data-activates=languageDropdown]'))
```